# Should I explicitly close asyncio.create_subprocess_shell process?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have the following function, which opens a program and prints out the output one character at a time:

```
async def run_command():
    st = os.stat('./myprogram')
    os.chmod('./myprogram', st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC ) 
    command = "./myprogram -command"


    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    while True:
        output = await proc.stdout.read(1)
        if not output:
            return
        yield output.decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
```

This function doesn't explicitly close the process after it's called and I will have to call it repeatedly, multiple times. Is it neccessary to explicitly close the process to avoid memory problems or other problems of some sort and if yes, how can it be done properly?